# Manipulate a list to solve a puzzle

Tags: python, list, puzzle

I have a list :

```
mylist=[[1,2],[2,3,5],[1,3],[5,8,6],[5,9],[4],[7],[6,8,9],[4,9,8,6]]
```

It's a line of a sudoku, with every lists representing the possibilites for every case.

My goal is to make a function that would remove `5` from `mylist[1]`; because `1`, `2` and `3` can only be in `list[0]` or `[1]` or `[2]`.

I'm looking for a hint

I've come up with

```
def epure(dimension, length):
    repeated=[i for sublist in [x for x in dimension if len(x)==length] for i in sublist]
    repeated=list(set([x for x in repeated if repeated.count(x)==length]))
    for n in dimension:
        for item in repeated:
            if item in n and len(n)!=length:
                n.remove(item)
    return dimension
```

But it's a fail and I'm struggling now.

Comment: Why are you returning your input as your output, 
you should return repeated instead of return dimension

Comment: What the function does is :
- check items in dimension(my_list)
- if an item is repeated n times with n==length of a list : remove the item from any other lists of different size.
- then return the dimension modified.

The output is okay, its the function that fails to achieve what i want.

Comment: give the desired output cause from what you are saying and what function is doing they both are two completely different things. Give desired output with given mylist as input.

Comment: lets say i pass the list [[1,2][1,3][2,3][4,5,3,2,1]] into my function. 
The output will be [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[4,5]].

I want a function so that if my input is [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3,4],[4]]
The output would be [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[4]]

Comment: you have 2 arguments what is value of length you've taken is it 2

Comment: Where as you're getting your desired result from this too , input epure(mylist,1) where mylist = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3,4],[4]]

Comment: code makes me feel so dumb sometime.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I guess you weren't passing all the arguments , Happy to help.

Comment: Taking it to a different direction - iterating over all the relevant permutation using itertools.permutations, filtering the illegal ones based on myList and saving in the side the relevant options.